# Make Mathjax underscore the same height as other characters

Tags: html, css, mathjax

Here is the latex I am using with Mathjax.

`\class{mathjaxCursor}{\text{_}}`

...and here is the css:

```
.mathjaxCursor
{
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: red;
}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Now some different latex:

```
5\class{mathjaxCursor}{\text{_}}
```

Same CSS but this produces:

[image]

I've included the red background to illustrate the problem. When the 5 comes along the height of the underscore is the full font height, without it the height is just the height of the underscore. Can you suggest a change to the CSS so that the underscore has a normal character height?

The reason being, when I wrap a root around the underscore it comes out looking like this:

[image]

The centre of the root symbol is at the level of the underscore, whereas it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: The next to last screenshot looks like a bug. Otherwise, you're describing the the fact that MathJax creates tight bounding boxes around characters; this is intended and [this discussion](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3/issues/138) might be helpful. General advice is not use CSS to modify MathJax output but modify the input, e.g. using the [bbox extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#bbox).

Comment: Thank you, I think it's intended as you say. In the end I did change the input using the vphantom approach from scraaappy - a lot better than trying to work against all the formatting mathsjax is already doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [\vphantom{...}](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#v) to simulate the height of any chararacters

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" async></script>


$$\sqrt{\vphantom{1}\class{mathjaxCursor}{\text{_}}}$$
```

or explore other options

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async></script>


$$\sqrt{\class{mathjaxCursor}{\text{_}}}$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but adding another character (1 in this case) after the underscore with the same colour as the background works.

```
5\class{mathjaxCursor}{\text{_}}\class{white}{1}
```

CSS:

```
.white
{
 color: white;
 font-size:xx-small;
}
```

It does leave a little gap to the right of the cursor which is not ideal.

Comment: FYI this is problematic for accessibility as the 1 will be exposed, e.g., to screenreaders; using `\vphantom` will hide it both visually and accessibly.

Comment: Yes it was a bit of a fudge, vphantom works brilliantly.